# RSpec: ActionController::UrlGenerationError: for custom url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Have gone through othe similar questions but the problem is not solved.

Test:

```
expect{
   post message_direct_create_path(friend.id), params: {message_direct: 
   FactoryBot.attributes_for(:message_direct, user_id: user.id, 
                             friend_id: friend.id)}
}.to change{MessageDirect.count}.by(1)
```

Route:

```
post '/message_directs/:friend_id', to: 'message_directs#create', as: 'message_direct_create'
```

Error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
    No route matches {:action=>"/message_directs/1", 
:controller=>"message_directs", :message_direct=>{:text=>"Sends 
Message", :user_id=>1, :friend_id=>1}}
```

I have also tried
`:create` and `"/message_directs/#{friend.id}"` but the error is still same

Comment: Can you share you spec here ?

Comment: controller spec or request spec?

Comment: Controller spec

Comment: Are you able to access this POST url in your application? Compare with server log for that.

Comment: Yeah i can access this through form in browser